# when should I use the Webservice attribute System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, attributes

When should we add this attribute to an asp.net webservice ?

```
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure at all how this has to do with a webservice.

See the [ToolboxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.toolboxitemattribute.aspx) at MSDN. The [constructor you mentioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1k7z59.aspx), is used to specify  a default type of toolbox item typically for a custom control.

As in this [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.toolboxitem.aspx) you can use this attribute to customize how your UserControl shows on the Visual Studio toolbox.