# WebService class and the ToolboxItem attribute

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

When I create a web service class, along with standard `WebService` and `WebServiceBinding` there's an additional, curious attribute:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class TestWS : System.Web.Services.WebService
```

I was wondering if there's a secretly hidden, very important reason to have the `ToolboxItem` attribute there (and it's necessary to add `using System.ComponentModel` just for it too). I'm usually removing that line and, rather obviously, nothing bad happens. Am I safe to assume that it's only there as a foolproof way to stop especially creative users from trying to somehow drag & drop it from toolbox to somewhere?

What I mean is this attribute seems so unnecessary there it's almost suspicious. There are probably many other things that could be added 'just in case people have strange ideas', so why `ToolboxItem` on a web service class out of all things? Were potential users judged to be possibly too creative for their own good or is there actually a hidden meaning behind it?

Answer (score 1):

If you add `[ToolboxItem(false)]` attribute;

in the solution explorer when you double click .asmx file it will automatically open .cs file instead of .asmx file.

Just a tiny tiny trick :)

Answer (score 0):

duplicated [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394807/when-should-i-use-the-webservice-attribute-system-componentmodel-toolboxitemfal)? 
below the answer

> Not sure at all how this has to do with a webservice.
>
> See the [ToolboxItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.toolboxitemattribute.aspx) at MSDN. The [constructor you mentioned](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1k7z59.aspx),
>   is used to specify  a default type of toolbox item typically for a
>   custom control.
>
> As in this [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.design.toolboxitem.aspx) you can use this attribute to
>   customize how your UserControl shows on the Visual Studio toolbox.

Comment: I've already seen it, thanks. I do think my question is broader than what that one covered though.

Answer (score -1):

It is said it's used because the **web-service shouldn't show up in the toolbox**.

But i wonder how a webservice would find a place in toolbox. If someone can explain it with an example it would be better!

Comment: 'It is said...' Please, can you link who says it? Also do not post question inside of answer, instead comment on the question please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315978/why-system-componentmodel-toolboxitemfalse-is-coming-in-asp-net-web-service

I read that as an answer in many technical blogs!
Sorry about my curiosity questions in answers!